# Why does this code print 6 instead of 5?

Tags: c++, clang, addition

I don't know how much strange this question might be for you: why does this code print 6 instead of 5? as far I know, should be using usual arithmetic here since once I haven't overloaded the `+` operator and `2+3 = 3+2 = 5` (as far I know)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum A
{
    A_A,
    A_B
};

struct Foo
{
    Foo(int, int, enum A);
    int x;
    int y;
    enum A flags;
};

struct Baa : Foo
{
    Baa(int, int);
    void show();
};


Foo::Foo(int a, int b, enum A aflags)
{
    x = a;
    y = b;
    flags = aflags;
}

Baa::Baa(int c, int d)
    : Foo(c, d, A_B)
{
}

void Baa::show()
{
    if(flags == A_A)
        printf("a = [%d]\n", x + y);
    else if(flags == A_B)
        printf("b = [%d]\n", y + y);
    else
        puts("unknow flag");
}

int main()
{
    Baa *b = new Baa(2, 3);
    b->show();
}
```

output:

```
b = [6]
```

I was having another problem accessing member value of derived class --if you want to know, I was getting `0` instead of actual value, so to get the actual value I needed to cast this to type of derived class, like this `int x = ((BaseCLass*)this)->n` and it worked. So I begun to write a short version of my code to post here on OS and ask for help but now I found this problem. What am I missing?

Comment: Constructor Baa() is accessing Foo() constructor with A_B flag set. Don't you think? It therefore adds y+y;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
printf("b = [%d]\n", y + y);
```

Don't you mean to be `x+y` instead of `y+y` ? So, 3+3 is 6 which is correct.

Comment: That's what the code has for the case where `flags == A_A`.  So perhaps the design is off.

Comment: Oh God, I need sleep. I don't believe I come to SO to ask this. :(

Comment: @TheMask Don't worry. It happens. Take a break.

Answer (score 3):

you are creating `Baa` object with:

```
Baa *b = new Baa(2, 3);
```

what happen next is:

```
Baa::Baa(int c, int d)
    : Foo(c, d, A_B)  // < flag A_B !
{
}
```

and what it does is:

```
Foo::Foo(int a, int b, enum A aflags)
{
    x = a;
    y = b;
    flags = aflags;
}
```

then in `show` method you do:

```
else if(flags == A_B)
        printf("b = [%d]\n", y + y);
```

And y + y = 3 + 3 = 6. Where is the confusion?

---

side note: where is `delete b;`?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the key line is:

```
else if(flags == A_B)
    printf("b = [%d]\n", y + y);
```

The `Baa` constructor sets `flags` to `A_B`.  So `show()` will output `y + y`, that is, 3 + 3 = 6.